# How to I write $\frac{7^{2n}}{4^{3n}}$ as a geometric series?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I am trying to write $$\frac{7^{2n}}{4^{3n}}$$ as a geometric series which has the form:$$\sum\limits_{i=0}^n{ar^n}$$.

I'm not sure if I should get in the form $$\left(\frac{7}{4}\right)^{2n}$$ (after eliminating one power of 4 from the denominator [which I'm not sure how to do]).

My question has 2 parts:

1. Can I write the geometric series as $$\left(\frac{7}{4}\right)^{2n}$$ ignoring the fact that the base is raised to 2n instead of just n?
2. If so, how do I eliminate one power of 4 from the denominator?

Comment: You can write this as $(\frac{7^2}{4^3})^n=(\frac{49}{64})^n$

Comment: Wait, you are trying to consider $\sum(7/4)^{2n}$? That would diverge badly...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the laws of exponents:

$$\frac{7^{2n}}{4^{3n}} = \frac{\left(7^2\right)^n}{\left(4^3\right)^n}= \frac{49^n}{64^n}=\left(\frac{49}{64}\right)^{n}$$

Answer (score 2):

For students who feel weak with exponent manipulation:

$a$ is the initial term. So just evaluate it at $n=0$ and you have $a$. (It's homework so I'm not giving the result.)

$r$ is the constant ratio between terms. So write down the first few terms by evaluating at $n=0$, $n=1$, and just to confirm, at $n=2$. See what ratio you are multiplying by at each step to go from $a_0$ to $a_1$ to $a_2$, etc.

This approach is nice if you would rather avoid exponent manipulation. It may be more helpful when you are trying to do the same task with more complicated geometric terms like say $\frac{2^{n-3}3^{4n+7}}{5^{n/2}}$, where this approach lets you (more) quickly see that $a=\frac{2187}{8}$, and $r=\frac{162}{\sqrt{5}}$ if you feel weak with exponent manipulation.

Comment: (I have deleted now useless comments.)